# Avoid garbage with nodejs app using foreverjs and running on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, garbage-collection, forever

According to [Heroku doc, to avoid garbage](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/11/10/node-habits-2016#7-avoid-garbage), you can provide flags to V8 in your Procfile:

```
web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 server.js
```

However, my app uses [foreverjs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), and I use the following instruction in the Procfile:

```
web: ./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js
```

Is there a way to provide flags like `--max_old_space_size` or `gc_interval=100` and still use [foreverjs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using pm2 not forever but as it seems that forever as this syntax :

```
usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
```

I would try to put those in the script-options part :

```
./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100
```

Either way, I wouldn't force the timing of the gc...
The max_old_space_size should be in acordance to the RAM you have available for your node process, and in your case, if your node process take more than ~500M of RAM it should trigger a gc call by himself.

Comment: thank you, I had missed the 'SCRIPT [script-options]' bit! Do you mean I should use '--optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460' but drop  '--gc_interval=100' ?

Comment: Yup, only do that if you have trouble with memory or looking for memory leak.

Comment: Should this be `./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 start -c "node --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100"  server.js?